# Text boot without text console: agetty problem in Fedora 36

Tags: linux, fedora, boot, console, autologin

I have always used text+console boot without graphic interface. This includes the login, that is also text only since I do some sync stuff at login time, specifically on `tty1` where I have an autologin script, that executes the following command through the file `/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf`:

```
/usr/sbin/agetty --autologin <myusername> --noclear %I 38400 linux
```

I just upgraded to Fedora 36 (from 35), and the boot goes fine until the very last step. Instead of showing me a text login prompt, it shows a black screen with an underscore at the top left.

Why?

The command `systemctl` goes well except precisely for one red line:

```
● getty@tty1.service    loaded failed failed    Getty on tty1
```

In the logs, I can see an error:

```
agetty[4565]: /dev/tty1: "cannot get controlling tty: Operation not permitted"
agetty[4565]: setting terminal attributes failed: Input/output error
```

I can see this error in the console each time I try as root

```
 service getty@tty1.service start
```

I don't know what went wrong, but it seems the agetty command changed?

**EDIT**:

If I put the line:

```
ExecStart=-/usr/sbin/agetty --autologin <myusername> --noclear tty1 38400 linux
```

in the file `/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf` the autologin works. Yet, if I change to

```
ExecStart=-/home/<myusername>/bin/myautologinscript.sh
```

with the same line, it doesn't!!

Comment: Possibly needs to be the session leader. Try `exec agetty...` instead of `agetty...` in your script.

Comment: Seeing the rest of `systemctl show getty@tty1.service` would probably help.

Comment: Yes! Just adding the `exec` in front of hte agetty did it. But why? Why it wasn't necessary before? It would be nice if you write this as a solution and explain why it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `cannot get controlling tty: Operation not permitted` error by `agetty` is returned by `agetty` when the `TIOCSCTTY` `ioctl()` it makes so the terminal device becomes the controlling terminal of `agetty`'s session fails.

It issues that `ioctl()` if the terminal currently doesn't control any session, or if it controls a session whose id is not `agetty`'s pid.

From the `tty_ioctl(2)` man page:

> ```
> TIOCSCTTY
>       Argument: int arg
>
>       Make the given terminal the controlling terminal of the  calling
>       process.   The  calling process must be a session leader and not
>       have a controlling terminal already.  For this case, arg  should
>       be specified as zero.
>
>       If  this  terminal is already the controlling terminal of a dif‐
>       ferent session group, then the ioctl fails  with  EPERM,  unless
>       the caller has the CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability and arg equals 1, in
>       which case the terminal is stolen, and all processes that had it
>       as controlling terminal lose it.
> ```

So, it won't work if `agetty` is not a session leader.

If you start a script that runs `agetty` in a child process instead of starting `agetty` directly, then the shell will be a session leader, and `agetty` will not.

Using `exec agetty` will run `agetty` in the same process as the shell (will replace the shell) and then `agetty` will be session leader.

<strike>If that worked in the previous version of Fedora with the same modus operandi, my guess would be that `systemd` had already made the terminal device the controlling terminal of the session, may by calling `open()` on it without the `O_NOCTTY` flag. But even then, having `agetty` not being the session leader sounds like a bad idea.</strike>

(I stroke that as in that case the controlled session would still not match `agetty`'s pid, so it would still try to issue the `TIOCSCTTY`; I don't have another explanation for now).

Comment: Excellent! I would have never guessed this by myself. Thanks for the thorough explanation!!